# iOS how can I turn Address into GPS coordinate (geocoding) in 2015?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, gps, geocoding

I'm looking at the [documentation of classes that come with Google Maps for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/) and see that it allows for GPS to Address conversion (Reverse Geocoding with `GMSGeocoder`). There's also a `GMSPlacePicker` for manual place picking, however, I don't see anything about regular geocoding.

**How can I perform programmatic Geocoding of addresses to GPS coordinates using objective-c?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following link. Just replace Youraddress with actual address

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Youraddress

Get API key at https://console.developers.google.com
Enable `Google Maps JS API` and `Geocoding API`
For example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=MEDICAL%20CENTER%20OF%20PEACH%20COUNTY,GA&key=YourGeocodingAPIKey
```

The limit seems to be 25000 calls per day at 1 call per second from a single client

Comment: Awesome, I intend to add all the boilerplate code to call this asynchronously. It seems that the call limit for this API is 25000 calls per day

Comment: Yes 25000 is more than enough for a device.

Comment: Something to note is that the Google Maps API does not verify addresses while there are other geocoding APIs that do provide address verification along with their geocoding services